# Retrieve response informaton in view

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I'm using ASP.NET Controller accessing account data to another database. I'm doing a login where it gets an ID and checks if it's a Mentor or Student.

With this information we want it to be used in a .js file we have thats makes a get request to our server. We want to send an ID here and later other informations.

We have this controller:

```
public IActionResult Calendar(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {

        Student student = null;
        Mentor mentor = null;

        if (loginViewModel.UserType == 0)
        {
            student = db.GetStudentObject(loginViewModel.Id);
        }
        else if (loginViewModel.UserType == 1)
        {
            mentor = db.GetMentorObject(loginViewModel.Id);
        }

        if (student != null)
        {
            return View(student.Id); 
        }if(mentor != null)
        {
            return View(mentor.Id);
        }

        return View("Index");

    }
```

When our view is initialized we want to send an ajax request where we use the Id we sent to the view

```
eventSources: [
        {
            url: '/api/Bookings?id=' + id, //we need to access the Id here
            color: 'blue',   
            textColor: 'white'  
        }
    ],
```

How can we retrieve the Id from the controller we are sending to the view? I know this can be solved by making a static class however is there a better options?

Comment: Assuming the above code is in the view, then just inject the value using Razor e.g.: `url: '/api/Bookings?id=' + @Model.ID` . The resulting JS will contain the ID hard-coded, assuming that's what you want?

Comment: You don't need to send an ajax request if you set model data on the view.

Comment: @Crowcoder in this particular circumstance, the fullCalendar product works best when a dynamic ajax-based data source is defined, since it auto-fetches data for different periods of time depending on the time period being viewed by the user. If this data was statically part of the model, then all the possible events in the database would have to be fetched up-front. Depending on the amount of data and how far back it goes in history, this might not be very efficient.

Comment: @ADyson What if it is in a separate js file?

Comment: @BorisGrunwald in that case I would expect that (for flexibility) the call to fullCalendar would be already encapsulated in a function and one could pass the ID to the function as a parameter. The function call would be in the view and get the ID in just the same way as I showed. Or the approach taken in the accepted answer using a proxy hidden field. Either will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//Accessing the Id on JS file:

'/api/Bookings?id=' + $('#Id').val();
```

```html
@*
if the view is binding to a complex model, you must return View(model), instead of View(model.Id) on controller.
assuming that is a complex model, you have in your view (cshtml):
*@

@model Xpto.Models.MyViewModel

@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.ID) //to access the property on JS file.
```